# Django 1.8 & Gmail - SMTPAuthenticationError Username and Password not accepted

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I'm really not sure what I've done wrong.

Settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email_address@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

In `python manage.py shell`:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('test', 'content', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
return mail.send()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 303, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 67, in open
self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in login
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257by17sm25608295wib.18 - gsmtp')
```

- I've tried http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.
- I've set it to [allow less secure apps access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?vid=1-635755814963531983-2694181562665504860).
- Google considers the password as secure.
- 2 Step Verification is not enabled.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Do you have 2-step verification?

Comment: Nope, added to above

Comment: I solved it, my own fault, see the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own mistake. All of the above steps in my question are correct.

I ran `from django.conf import settings`, changed the username/password details in the file itself, then imported `settings` again, thinking the changes would be imported over the previous import. They weren't. Using a new shell worked!

Comment: I am having the same issue but i don't get how did you solved it. You just edited settings.py?

Comment: You need to edit settings.py with your email details, save it, and then open the shell and import settings. Silly mistake, but that's what I did wrong. If you import settings.py first, the shell has  o way of knowing you've made a change to the file unless you reload it

Comment: Yes, need to restart the shell when changing the password. Also with environment variables, otherwise the shell will keep using the old environment variables. That was my problem.